# Designing Different JSON Responses from a WebService in case of Error

Tags: java, android, json

I have an android client that searches for POI across a location.
I currently parse the JSON using Jackson parser, so the return type of AsyncTask's DoInBackground is SearchResponse.
But the problem happens when Error is returned from the server saying it could NOT connect to third party servers.
In that case I want to return an Error something like ErrorResponse.
One way is to implement a BaseResponse class and all responses (ErrorResponse,SearchResponse can extend from it) and have it as a return type.
Is this the right way to do this? Can somebody suggest any better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have a wrapping message that includes a node for the content in the successful case but also includes nodes for error ID / message?